# mailkit sendMail doubts

Tags: c#, asp.net, sendmail, mailkit

I have a server in cloud (asp.net) and i install mailkit to provide my clients to send emails from my application with their owns emails account.

One of my problem is a email that he can send 3 emails and then the next email is rejected by the server:

> "Message: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did
>   not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond 213.190.193.29:25"

Other problem is that they send to his mail and he recieves a "SPAM".

Can help me?

Comment: Can you show us your code? Can be hard to diagnose the error when we don't know your implementation. With regards to emails being flagged as spam, that is on the recipient's side. Your email address needs to be added to the safe senders list.

Comment: I'm not working in the office today. I'll put the code tomorrow! 
My aplication send's a email test like outlook to same email to test the connection.. it's strange the same adress assumes spam..

Comment: SMTP servers often have a limit as to the number of times you can connect to it in a short period of time. This is most likely the problem.

Comment: Maybe is the our server that is in Ireland that connects with Portuguese SMTP server blocks because is not acessing in same country? Locally i don't have this problem... Whats the diference bettween Outlook and this application, talking only about SMTP?

Comment: There's no difference. The problem is just that the connection timed out because the server didn't respond. This can happen with all internet protocols. You just have to try again.

Comment: Which is the difference send mail via Outlook (always works) and my code (sometimes works)?

Answer (score 0):

```
    {
        emailID = "";
        // Nova Mensagem 
        var message = new MimeMessage();
        try
        {
            // Acede aos parâmetros do email caso este seja do gestobrigweb gmail.com
            if (emailSettings.email == "gestobrigweb@gmail.com") {
                EmailProvider provider = new EmailProviders().GetEmailProvider(Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["gestObrigWebProviderID"]));

                if (emailSettings.provider == null)
                    emailSettings.provider = provider;
            }

            // UserName
            string userName = emailSettings.email;   
            // Password
            if (userPass == "")
                userPass = cripter.Decrypt(emailSettings.pass);

            // From
            message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(emailSettings.email, emailSettings.email));

            // TO
            if (recipient.Contains(";"))
                foreach (string recipt in recipient.Split(';'))
                    message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(recipt, recipt));
            else
                if (recipient.Contains(","))
                    foreach (string recipt in recipient.Split(','))
                        message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(recipt, recipt));
                else
                  message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(recipient, recipient));


            // Se Assume CC
            if (assumeCC)
                message.Cc.Add(new MailboxAddress(emailSettings.email,emailSettings.email));

            // Destinatário
            if (cc != "")
            {
                if (cc.Contains(";"))
                    foreach (string emailCC in cc.Split(';'))
                    message.Cc.Add(new MailboxAddress(emailCC,emailCC));
                else
                    message.Cc.Add(new MailboxAddress(cc, cc));
            }

            // Assunto
            message.Subject = subject;

            // Body (Mensagem)
            var bodyBuilder = new BodyBuilder();
            bodyBuilder.HtmlBody = body;
            message.Body = bodyBuilder.ToMessageBody();

            // Envio
            using (var client = new SmtpClient())
            {
                // For demo-purposes, accept all SSL certificates (in case the server supports STARTTLS)
                client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;

                client.Connect(emailSettings.emailServer, emailSettings.serviceType, false);

                // Note: since we don't have an OAuth2 token, disable
                // the XOAUTH2 authentication mechanism.
                client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");

                // Note: only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication
                client.Authenticate(userName, userPass);

                client.Send(message);
                client.Disconnect(true);
                return true;
            }

        }
```